# Field of Inertial Forces

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, general-relativity, reference-frames, acceleration, equivalence-principle

Although inertial forces are just our mathematical creation to help apply Newton's law even in non-inertial frames, can we assume or is it (mathematical proof) that inertial forces also create its field.

I think it does so, because when we say that we cannot distinguish between gravity and accelerated motion, we assume them to be same.

Is it just as assumption or a correct assumption?

Answer (score 0):

Inertial forces behave like any other force apart from not deriving from an interaction with other bodies. In particular, the inertial forces that depend on the position may define a vector field. That is the case of the centrifugal force, or the the case of static tidal force in the non-rotating, non-inertial reference frame of a planet's center of mass. Both correspond to conservative fields with their own potential energy. However, another inertial force, the Coriolis force, depends on the velocity, and therefore, it does not correspond to a vector field on the configuration space.

It is not necessary a special proof for the previous statements. It is enough to look at the expression of these forces in the non-inertial reference frame.

Answer (score 0):

One way to arrive at what you suggest is to introduce the assumption that the phenomenon of inertia is mediated by a field.

In terms of newtonian mechanics you would then have two fields with a common coupling factor: the factor '$m$' for mass.

In terms of General Relativity the description of Inertia and the description of Gravity are unified into a single theory.

In the 1990's [John Stachel](https://www.bu.edu/cphs/ces/research/john-stachel/) proposed as name for that unified theory:
*Theory of the inertia-gravitational field*

About John Stachel:
John Stachel started his career as a physicist, and later moved on to History and Philosophy of Science. John Stachel's main interest is to extend and communicate the understanding of the concepts that go into General Relativity.

From the Wikipedia article:
John Stachel is head of the Boston Center for Einstein Studies.

Publication of the [Collected Papers of Albert Einstein](https://einsteinpapers.press.princeton.edu/) started in 1977, and is projected to encompass a total of 25 volumes. The first two volumes were published during John Stachel's tenure as editor.

(All of the content of the 'Collected papers project' is accessible on the Collected Papers project website.)

In general:
The scholars who are the most involved in studying the concepts of Relativistic physics are historians of science. Tracing the development of ideas over time is their very profession. After the introduction of the expression 'theory of the inertia-gravitational field' other historians of science have also started using that expression.

(I noticed that there are two different spellings in circulation: 'inertia-gravitational field', and 'inertio-gravitational field.)